# ffmpeg : How can I receive from /dev/video0 and store raw image on my pi

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi connected to a USB camera.

I'm trying to receive a stream from `/dev/video0`.

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h

int main() {

    AVFormatContext   *pFormatCtx = NULL;

    av_register_all();

    avdevice_register_all();

    AVInputFormat *inputFormat = av_find_input_format("v4l2");

    AVDictionary *options = NULL;

    av_dict_set(&options, "framerate", "25", 0);

    printf("%d\n",avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, "/dev/video0 ", inputFormat, &options));

    retrun 0;
}
```

Am I right?

How can I store raw image to my Raspberry Pi?